# Is it OK to route power traces underneath an MCU?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers

I am working on a 2 layer PCB: a STM32F405 break out board with I2C, SPI and UART. I am trying to minimize traces on the bottom ground plane and have arrived at a layout in which I have routed power traces underneath the MCU on the top layer.

Is it good practice to do that? Can the heating of the traces affect the MCU?

Attached is a snapshot of my layout. The highlighted traces are the power traces - 3.3V.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: How much current do you expect to run on those traces? Have you calculated how much the traces heat up with that current?

Comment: These traces look a little big if you're just powering a uC. But may I ask, why do you need a GND plane on both the top and bottom of your board? You can make the top plane a power plane and connect the GND nets to a via on the bottom of the PCB.

Comment: @Justme It is a breakout board for an STM32F405 board. My expected current is anything between 500mA to 1A.

Comment: @Jay My question, is it acceptable to have a power plane on top?

Comment: @Huzefia When designing a low voltage PCB (like 28V or less. This is just a ballpark number, so take it with a grain of salt), it's absolutely acceptable. Just make sure you don't have any narrow pours of copper on your plane.